# Assembly Language [MASM] Exception Thrown Error

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

This is my MASM code:

```
.data
  promptMonth BYTE "Enter month ", 0
  promptDay BYTE "Enter day ", 0
  promptYear BYTE "Enter year ", 0
.code
  main PROC
  p1:
    mov edx, OFFSET promptMonth
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov ebp, eax

  p2:
    mov edx, OFFSET promptDay
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov esp, eax

  p3:
    mov edx, OFFSET promptYear
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov edi, eax
  main ENDP       ; Added by edit
```

For some reason, when the code gets to the "WriteString" function at in `p3`, I get an error

> Exception thrown at 0x00403687 in Project.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation accessing location 0x00000000".

I don't understand why, because `p1` and `p2` run perfectly fine and they're almost the same code as `p3`.

Answer (score 1):

`esp` is the stack pointer register.  On x86, when you `call` a function, the stack is used for passing parameters and the return address.

When you execute `mov esp, eax` you are setting the stack pointer to be whatever is returned from `ReadInt` (which, from its name, I guess is a user-supplied value), which you gave as `0`.

The exception code `0xC0000005` is an [access violation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/836721/you-receive-a-0xc0000005-access-violation-error-message) because the `call WriteString` instruction tried to put the return address from your calling code into location `0x00000000`, which is a null pointer.

Solution: to store the return value from the call to `ReadInt`, use a register other than `esp`.

Also, unless you know that you aren't using the designated frame pointer register (`ebp`) for its intended purpose, you shouldn't use that as a general-purpose register either.

Answer (score 0):

You are messing up the *Stack Pointer* with the instruction

```
mov esp, eax
```

Why do you even do that?
Putting the return value in `EAX` to the stack pointer is a **really** bad idea.

The first attempt to put `EAX` to `EBP` is useless, at best, so it doesn't have any effect so far.

But replacing the *Stack Pointer* `ESP` with a return value does mess up everything.

**Don't do that!**
It's no surprise that the program crashes afterwards (@p3).
So, to fix your program, do the following:

Remove

```
mov ebp, eax
```

and

```
mov esp, eax
```

from your code.
This should fix your major problems.

The last one

```
mov edi, eax
```

doesn't affect the program flow, so you can do as you want.

Comment: Note: unless `ebp` is actually being used as the frame pointer (you don't have to do that if you use only `esp`-relative accesses ) it can be used as a non-volatile GPR.

Comment: @GovindParmar: Of course, you're right. But this depends on the compilation options - is the program compiled with a stack frame or not? Assembling a program also depends on  that. But it is safer to assume that there is a stack frame than not. Hence, I advised to remove the instruction affecting it.